# Using jib-gradle-plugin to build multi project Dropwizard app

Tags: gradle, jib

I have a gradle project I'd like to build using `jib`. The project contains subprojects arranged like so:

```
root
|
|build.gradle.kts
|settings.gradle.kts
|web/
    |build.gradle.kts
    |src/
        |main/
             |java....(etc)
             |resources/
                       |config.yaml
```

Note that the :web subproject contains a `config.yaml` in its resources.

I have my jib building a docker image in the root build.gradle with the appropriate entry point but I'm unsure how to get the `:web` subproject's resources included in the image.

My `jib` task in the root `build.gradle` is as follows:

```
tasks {
    jib {
        configurations {
            container {
                mainClass = applicationMainClassName
                args = listOf("server", "$appRoot/resources/config.yaml")
                ports = listOf("8080")
                jvmFlags = listOf("-server", "-Djava.awt.headless=true", "-XX:+UseG1GC", "-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100", "-XX:+UseStringDeduplication")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried using both `$appRoot/config.yaml` as well as `$appRoot/resources/config.yaml` in the args for the container with no luck.

The error after building the image and trying to run it is as follows:

```sh
> docker run my_app

java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /resources/config.yaml not found
    at io.dropwizard.configuration.FileConfigurationSourceProvider.open(FileConfigurationSourceProvider.java:18)
    at io.dropwizard.configuration.SubstitutingSourceProvider.open(SubstitutingSourceProvider.java:37)
    at io.dropwizard.configuration.BaseConfigurationFactory.build(BaseConfigurationFactory.java:80)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.parseConfiguration(ConfiguredCommand.java:126)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:74)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:78)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:93)
    at my.web.HelloWorldApplication.main(HelloWorldApplication.java:17)
```

Answer (score 1):

So upon further reading of the jib docs, all resources are mounted into `/app/resources`. To pull in all of my sub project resources, I did the following in my root project `build.gradle.kts`:

```
// collect all subproject resources
tasks.processResources {
    from(subprojects.flatMap {
        it.sourceSets.main.get().resources.srcDirs
    })
}
```

The one thing here is that you cannot have files of the same name in different subprojects.